# HAVING clause in EF Linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I want to get a list of customer IDs and the number of orders placed by that customer. Filter conditions are:

1. Orders with a total of $10 or less will not be counted.
2. Customers who did not place at least 3 orders (each with a total of $10 or more) will not be listed.

So, I would do the following in SQL:

```
SELECT customerID, COUNT(*)
FROM Orders
WHERE orderTotal > 10
GROUP BY customerID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

And in EF, I think this could be expressed as:

```
dbContext.Order
.Where(o => o.orderTotal > 10)
.GroupBy(o => o.customerID)
.Where(g => g.Count() > 2)
.ToList();
```

But this produces the following SQL that uses a derived table and a join rather than simply using a `HAVING` clause. I think this would be far from optimal in terms of performance. Is there a better way to formulate the case in EF so that the translated query will use the `HAVING` clause as it should?

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[customerID] AS [customerID], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 

FROM ( SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [customerID], 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[storeID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
    FROM   (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[customerID] AS [K1], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[orderTotal] > cast(10 as decimal(18))
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[customerID] ) AS [GroupBy1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[orderTotal] > cast(10 as decimal(18))) AND (([GroupBy1].[K1] = [Extent2].[customerID]) OR (([GroupBy1].[K1] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[customerID] IS NULL)))
    WHERE [GroupBy1].[A1] > 2
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[customerID] ASC, [Project1].[C2] ASC
```

Comment: Are you experiencing performance issue or are you just speculating?

Answer (score 5):

Well, the LINQ to Entities query is not equivalent of the SQL query because it returns a list of *groupings* (pair of key and matching elements) which has no SQL equivalent at all.

If you return just the `customerId` and the `Count` as in the SQL query:

```
db.Orders
.Where(o => o.orderTotal > 10)
.GroupBy(o => o.customerID)
.Select(g => new { customerId = g.Key, orderCount = g.Count() })
.Where(g => g.Count > 2)
.ToList();
```

then the SQL generated by EF would be pretty much the same as (or functionally equivalent to) the expected:

```sql
SELECT
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [customerID],
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Extent1].[customerID] AS [K1],
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[orderTotal] > cast(10 as decimal(18))
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[customerID]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
    WHERE [GroupBy1].[A1] > 2
```

Comment: So it never produces SQL with a HAVING clause?

Comment: @JohnL. I believe it will use `HAVING` if your Linq query does not ultimately return the data within each `IGrouping` and **only** uses aggregates (but the Linq query in this answer _does_ return all the inner data). Note that an outer-query with `WHERE` is (largely) equivalent and I'd be surprised if the DBMS came up with a substantially different execution plan compared to a hand-written query that used `HAVING`.